# Querying XML field in database table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database, t-sql

I have a table named VehicleHistoryBlob that has the following structure:

```
VehicleHistoryBlobId int PRIMARY KEY
VehicleHistoryBlob XML
```

I need to write SQL that finds all entries in VehicleHistoryBlob XML that have Bus as a parent node and Destination as a child node (Bus can have many Destinations, and the parent node in the XML is not always a Bus).

```
<Bus>
...
    <Destination>
            <Name>The big building</Name>
            <DestinationCode> A21301423 </DestinationCode>
            <DestinationAddress> 440 Mountain View Parade </DestinationAddress>
            <DestinationCountry> USA </DestinationCountry>
    </Destination>
</Bus>'
```

I need to query through the XML and find all entries that have Bus as a parent node and Destination as a child node, and pass the VehicleHistoryBlobId associated with the XML into my temporary table @tmpTable

```
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE(theints INT)
```

I have been trying to manipulate the .nodes function but I am struggling to yield accurate results due to my lack of experience with XML as a data type.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter row by certain condition on the XML column, you can use [`exist()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) method instead of `nodes()`. For example, the following query insert to `@temptable` `VehicleHistoryBlobId` where corresponding XML has `Bus` as root element and `Destination` child element :

```
INSERT INTO @tmpTable
SELECT v.VehicleHistoryBlobId 
FROM VehicleHistoryBlob v
WHERE v.VehicleHistoryBlob.exist('/Bus/Destination') = 1
```

**<kbd>[`sqlfiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e00b/1)</kbd>**

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much @har07